# Proof of closed ball by contradiction.

Tags: analysis

I want to show that the ball $B(x_{0}, r) = \{v \in V / ||x_{0}- v ||\leq r  \}$ is a closed ball. If we try to show that its complementary is an open ball, the proof is finished (I know it can be proven supposing that there is an open ball in every point the belongs to it). However, I am obsessed with showing it by contradiction, I mean, I want to show it stating that for the sake of contradiction, we suppose that the limit of the sequence $\{v_{i} \}_{i=1}^n$ does not belong to the ball. I want to reach a contradiction parting from this, but it is apparently impossible, and it should not be so. Can anyone show it this way?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\exists$ a limit point $e$ of $B(x_0, r)$ with $d(x_0, e) > r$, i.e. outside the ball. Then $\exists x \neq e \in B(e, r') \cap B(x_0, r)$ $\forall r' > 0$ by the definition of a limit point. Putting $r' = \frac{1}{2}\left(d(x_0, e)-r\right)>0$ gives a contradiction as $B(x_0, r) \cap B(e, r') = \varnothing$.

Comment: Wow, I would have never come up with that, thank you very much. My approaches implied trying to contradict by the definition of limit and with triangular inequality, but I could never find the contradiction that way, for any $\epsilon$

Comment: I was shaky on analysis through university, I think because the course didn't emphasise some of the fundamentals of metric spaces. It didn't start to click with me until studying Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin. The second chapter helped a lot. It's a classic book, maybe your library has a copy.

Comment: Thanks! My library has an online copy available, checking it out!